# Toran Proxy private repositories authentication

Tags: toran-proxy

I'm trying to add an private repository in Toran Proxy. However, it ends up with an authentication failure. How to setup the authentication for toran proxy?

Any help would be nice.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should ask you for authentication credentials for github and/or bitbucket according to your private packages locations, but anyway you can manually modify auth credentials by editing the following file `app/toran/composer/auth.json`